# Skip hidden inputs in Jquery serialize

Tags: jquery

I have forms with inputs of hidden and visible like below.In this example I want to serialize only name='country' which is not hidden

```
<form id="finalform">
<input type='hidden' name='sid' value='901271316' />
<input type='hidden' name='tco_currency' value='USD'>
<input   name='country' value='India' />
</form>
```

I tried below code but its serializing even hidden inputs.

```
var frm = $("form#finalform:visible");
 var add= JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use below code . `not(:hidden)` will not include input type hidden in `serialize()`

check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aksqggnn/1/)

```
var frm  = $('#finalform').find(":input:not(:hidden)").serialize();
```

Or

```
var frm  = $('#finalform :input:not(:hidden)').serialize();
```

DEMO

```js
var frm  = $('#finalform :input:not(:hidden)').serializeArray();

var frm1  = $('#finalform').find(":input:not(:hidden)").serializeArray();

$('#firstOutput').text(JSON.stringify(frm))
$('#secondOutput').text(JSON.stringify(frm1))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="finalform">
 <input type='hidden' name='sid' value='901271316' />
 <input type='hidden' name='tco_currency' value='USD'>
 <input   name='country' value='India' />
</form>


<div id="firstOutput"> </div>
<div id="secondOutput"> </div>
```

Answer (score 7):

I find this a cleaner way of doing it:

```
var frm = $('#finalform [type!="hidden"]').serialize()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make a temporary copy of it and remove the hidden inputs from it before serializing :

```
var form = $("#finalform").clone();
$(form).find("input[type=hidden]").remove()
var serialized = $(form).serializeArray();
```

Comment: $(form).find ? its still searching for other forms in page and serialize hidden inputs

Comment: No, $(form).find() digs inside the form's dom for everything that matches input[type=hidden]. Try it, it will work fine! It's **$(form)** not **$('form')** and it is not the same thing, the first is not a selector.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible solution with a demo.

```js
var notHidden = $('#finalform > :not(input[type=hidden])').serializeArray();

$('#itemsSerializedCount').text($(notHidden).length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20140204/json2.js"></script>
<form id="finalform">
<input type='hidden' name='sid' value='901271316' />
<input type='hidden' name='tco_currency' value='USD'>
<input   name='country' value='India' />
</form>

<lablel id="itemsSerializedCount"></label>
```

Here, the input control which is not hidden is serialized.